# how to keep 10 biggest integer while reading a list in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of integer in a list and want to keep the 10 biggest while I'm iterating over the list and keep them in a TreeSet. I'm using this code :

```
for(Integer i : list) {                
            if (treeSet.size() < 10) {                    
                treeSet.add(i);
            } else if (i > treeSet.last()) {
                treeSet.pollLast();
                treeSet.add(i);
            }
        }
```

but results is defferent when I change order of integers in list before running this code. Is my code true?

Comment: Side note: I assume that `TreeSet` is actually the name of a variable - if so: please take some time to read "java coding guidelines". Variable names start with lowercase letters. And in this case, the "deviation" from that style guide can cause a lot of wrong assumptions ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`treeSet` is holding its data in ascending order (first is the smallest), so you should be replacing first element, not last:

```
for(Integer i : list) {                
    if (treeSet.size() < 10) {                    
        treeSet.add(i);
    } else if (i > treeSet.first()) {
        treeSet.pollFirst();
        treeSet.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Collection.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) and get the desired number of results with [`List.subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)).

```
// Sort the arraylist
Collections.sort(list); 
//gets the last 10 item, last is the largest for ascending default sort
list.subList(list.size()-10, list.size());
```

Comment: For larger lists, this will not be very beneficial, performance wise: Sorting is `O(n*log(n))`, where the latter "n" is the size of the list. With a target collection where inserting/removing has `O(log(n))`, and where the size of the target collection is limited to, say, a small "k", the algorithm will have a running time of `O(n*log(k))` where `log(k)` is basically a small constant.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: Note that your approach is flawed in general (and this flaw is also present in the originally accepted answer): This may deliver wrong results when there are duplicate elements in the list. A random example where I noticed this is an input list like
>
> ```
> List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(
>      0, 8, 9, 7, 15, 13, 11, 1, 19, 14, 
>      17, 17, 13, 2, 15, 4, 4, 15, 1, 0);
> ```
>
> for which it returns
>
> ```
> [1, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19]
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> [4, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19]
> ```

---

A simple, straightforward solution would be the following:

```
private static <T> Collection<T> keepLargest(
    List<? extends T> list, Comparator<T> comparator, int n)
{
    TreeSet<T> treeSet = new TreeSet<T>(comparator);
    for(T t : list) 
    {                
        treeSet.add(t);
        while (treeSet.size() > n)
        {
            treeSet.pollFirst();
        }
    }
    return treeSet;
}
```

which can be called as

```
Collection<Integer> kept = 
    keepLargest(list, Comparator.naturalOrder(), 10);
```

One could now argue about the repeated insertions and removals (that could be avoided), but since the tree set is small, the `log(n)` for the insertion should be negligible. If this performance is highly relevant, one could consider using a similar approach with a `PriorityQueue` as well, or try to optimize this solution, but in its current form, it's very simple and not error-prone due to (premature?) optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with streams (if you can use Java 8):

```
final Comparator<Integer> order = Integer::compare;
List<Integer> collect = list.stream().sorted(order.reversed()).limit(10).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you could also use parallelStream() instead of stream() which should be faster.

http://blog.takipi.com/new-parallelism-apis-in-java-8-behind-the-glitz-and-glamour/